# .net 1- getting unque values for a column from datatable/dataview

Tags: asp.net

We are using .net 1 ,i know we should switch to higher but not
 in my hand.
I am trying to show unque values of a column returned from stored proc & putting in data tabel. rest of the column need to show all the values.

i googled and found below which seems not working in this version-
new DataView(myTable).ToTable(true, new string[]{"channel"});

Do we have any other simple method. i dont like to use for loop to iterate all the values and put in arraylist.

my code is as below=

```
    cmd = New SqlCommand("web_RetrieveClient", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientKey", SqlDbType.Int, 4)
    param.Value = lClientKey
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd![enter image description here][1]
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    conn.Close()
```

please see the result data of proc in image.
I need unique channelids.

thanks for the help in advance.
navya

Answer (score 0):

With .NET 1.1 your options are limited. The for loop to an array list might be your only choice as I don't think DataView can do DISTINCT.

Why can't you rewrite the stored procedure?

Comment: thanks Broam.
actually same proc is giving data for whole page and this channel id going into dropdown which selection will control rest of the column view.
what kind of re-write you mean?
kinda messy at DB level...dont have much control in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to do this would be:

- copy your stored procedure
- In the new stored procedure use DISTINCT in the select
- Call the new stored procedure

Comment: unfortunately i cant rewrite the proc as its used by other products.

Comment: yes that is why you should create a copy, the original will continue to be used by the other products